# How to get k-top error between two lists in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two float list `A` and `B`. They are same size. I want to print k-top error `(abs(A-B))`between them. For example

`A=[1,2,3,4], B=[3,0.5,2.5,3.85]`. Then k-top error with k=3 will show as

```
k_top error (k=3)
A=1, B=3, error=2
A=2, B=0.5, error=1.5
A=3, B=2.5, error=0.5
```

This is what I did

```
error=[]
for i in range (len(A)):
  error.append(math.abs(A[i]-B[i])
```

Comment: Did you mean top-k error?

Comment: Yes. K-top error. I will update my code

Comment: 3 of the max differences do you mean ? What about the `B=3` and `B=2.5` where do they come from ?

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong copy. I was fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def kError(A,B,k = 2):
    #    return sorted([(a,b,round(abs(a-b),2)) for a,b in zip(A,B)],
    #                  reverse=True, key = lambda x:x[2])[:k]
    return sorted([(a,b,abs(a-b)) for a,b in zip(A,B)],
                  reverse=True, key = lambda x:x[2])[:k]

A = [1,2,3,4] 
B = [2,1.5,0.5,3.85]
k = 2

for a,b,d in kError(A,B,k):
    print(f'A:{a} B:{b} err:{d}')
```

Output:

```
A:3 B:0.5 err:2.5
A:1 B:2 err:1
```

you might want to round off if you encounter floating point errors (change to the commented version).

Comment: Thanks. But I think it must be inverted. The first position must show the top error

Comment: Thanks. I accepted it as the first corrected answer

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get `k-top` max differences use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) method in combination with  `built-in` [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function.

Also, use a `lambda` function in order to sort list descending by `error` value.

```
sorted_list = sorted([[a, b, abs(a - b)]for (a, b) in zip(A, B)], reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[2])[:3]
for i in sorted_list:
    print('A = {0}, B = {1}, error = {2}'.format(str(i[0]),str(i[1]),str(i[2])))
```

Output

```
A = 1, B = 3, error = 2
A = 2, B = 0.5, error = 1.5
A = 3, B = 2.5, error = 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks. But I have to choose another answer because he provided early solution

Comment: No idea who was first - I added the sorting after he told me he wanted it sorted  :) +1 . Is there an advantage of using `for (a, b) in zip(A, B)` over `for a, b in zip(A, B)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want ?

```
from itertools import product

print(sorted([abs(a - b) for (a, b) in product(A, B)], reverse=True)[:3])

# [3.5, 2.85, 2.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to loop over the first `k` elements of the list, right?

```
def top_k_error(A, B, k):
    if len(A) < k or len(A) != len(B):
        return
    for i in range(k):
        a = A[i]
        b = B[i]
        error = abs(A[i] - B[i])
        print("A={}, B={}, error={}".format(a, b, error) )
```

Comment: This works only if the list is ordered by error to begin with?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: `A=[9,8,7,6]` , `B = [1,10,1,10]` - you do not print the `k` max errors but the first `k` ones.